# How to unit test image upload in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I've just started with Django REST Framework and I'm  trying to test a simple file upload enpoint.

I've written a barebones code as follows:

models.py

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    some_field = models.ForeignKey(SomeModel)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
class PhotoUpload(APIView):
    def post(self, request, filename, format='multipart'):
        image_file = request.FILES['file']
        print(image_file)
        return Response(status=204)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^api/photos/', PhotoUpload.as_view()),
```

Going through the docs, I've written a sample test case as follows:

tests.py

```
class PhotoUploadTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.oauth_header = _get_oauth2_header()

    def test_photo_upload(self):
        c = Client()
        response = c.get('/api/photos/', **self.oauth_header)
```

However, I'm stuck here and I don't know how to proceed.

I've also tried using curl as follows:

`curl --form image=@test.jpg http://localhost:8000/api/photos` but this gives me

`"Authentication credentials were not provided."`. How do I test my endpoint?

Comment: Generally you're doing it right. What kind of error/issue are you getting with the `c.get` approach? The curl method needs the authorization headers appended to it indeed..Is your endpoint accessible via basic auth? then you could do the following in your test: `response = self.client.get('/api/photos/', **{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode('USER:PASS')})`

Comment: @Martin, So when I just hit the `/api/photos/` in my browser, I get the Authorization issue. But when I hit it with curl, I get a trailing slash issue along with no authorization. I'm kind of lost because I'm new to DRF.

Comment: I suppose because in the curl example you dont have a slash after photos/ and Django's urls.py is quite strict about that.. So does your app accept basic authorization or only oauth? what error do you get in your test?

Comment: @Martin Even using `photos/` gives the same error. Apart from that it accepts only `oauth` and I couldn't find ways to test oauth endpoints.

Comment: OK, lets ignore the browser for now. Using curl - try doing `curl -H "Authorization: OAuth <ACCESS_TOKEN>" http://...` first (you'll obviously need an OAuth token) and see where you get from there.

Comment: What does `_get_oauth2_header` return? It's probably the key to this question, but it's missing from your post.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of testing when you need to login (in this case it uses a superuser):

```
# available to those with superuser permissions
self.superuser = User.objects.create_superuser(
    username='superuser',
    password='password'
)
self.client.login(username='superuser', password='password')

url = reverse('myurl', kwargs={})

request = self.client.get(url, format='json')
```